# Scaling the y axis up, while scaling the x axis down with D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am building an interactive figure to show the scale invariance of the 1/r function in javascript with D3.js. To do this, I need to scale the figure in the x-direction by a factor of k and in the y-direction by a factor of 1/k. To do this I can access the d3.event.transform and manually set the k factor for the y axis like so:

```
var newxScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)
// this does not feel good, neither does it really work
d3.event.transform.k = 1/ d3.event.transform.k
var newyScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)
d3.event.transform.k = 1/ d3.event.transform.k
```

as demonstrated in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/od9pcnut/44/

Changing the variables in the d3.event.transform feels incredibly wrong and messes up the zoom around the mouse position (the drawn line drifts off in some direction when I scale the figure). How can I tell the scale to scale by different factors in different directions, while retaining the zoom around mouse position feature?

Answer (score 0):

`d3.event.transform` is an instance of `d3.zoomIdentity`. You can build a new zoom Identity and rescale the X / Y scales with it:

```
const {x, y, k} = d3.event.transform; 

const newxScale = d3.zoomIdentity
  .translate(x, y)
  .scale(k)
  .rescaleX(xScale);

const newyScale = d3.zoomIdentity
  .translate(x, y)
  .scale(1 / k)
  .rescaleY(yScale);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This would be a way to mitigate the reassignment in the d3.event.transform, whose entries, as far as I know, should be treated as read-only. In the end, your proposed code does not really fix the problem of the y-axis drifting away when you zoom. (I did update the fiddle with your code, since this would probably be the best way to do what I was doing to this point...)